# How to receive a url from a client and use it with gethostbyname()

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send a message from a client to a server via sockets in python, specifically I would send a  url example "www.google.com". Then I would just display the Ip address. I'm using telnet as my client. So I type in the information

I tried a number of ways to turn the message into a string, still haven't found a solution. "I'm currently getting this error:

```
 socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
 Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "proxy_server.py", line 44, in handle_connection
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(str(message.decode('utf-8')))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Not sure how to fix this. Should I just use `split()` to get rid of the unwanted stuff when I first get the message and not use decode?

```
# Recieve message from the client
message = conn.recv(2024)
print(message)
print(message.decode('utf-8'))
# host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(message.decode('utf-8'))
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(str(message.decode('utf-8')))
print(host_ip)
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Just added the complete error message.

Comment: [Probable dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254394/name-or-service-not-known).

Comment: Are you getting a URL or a hostname? `www.google.com` is a hostname, `https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow` is a URL.

Comment: @DYZ No, doesn't help. From telnet if I enter "www.google.com". I want on my server side to print out the Ip address.

Comment: @Barmar I want to get the Ip of the hostname. Correction

Comment: What is the exact string you are sending into `gethostbyname`? (It would help if you show all your output instead of just the error.) You can't just send *any* string to it and expect success. Get rid of the socket `recv` (for debugging, that is). Just do: `import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname("string"))`. And, BTW, `message.decode('utf-8')` *will* be a string.

Comment: @GilHamilton In telnet I send "www.google.com".  The recv() get the message and stores it into the variable "message". I then use message.decode() to turn it into a string, then I pass that variable into the gethostbyname(). I then get the above error which I'm not sure why I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try harcoding the host to verify that the name resolution is working on the server side:

```
socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
```

Also, check the length of your input to get rid of any possible '\n'

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: You're right it does have extra characters. Makes sense.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it should. I'm not able to comment above due my reputation being lower than 50.